# Derivation of the compensating resistor in integrator with DC gain control

Tags: operational-amplifier, integrator

[image: Integrator with DC gain control, compensating resistor added]

Hi all in EE stackchange,

I wonder how the compensating resistor (\$R_3\$) in integrator with DC gain control equals \$R_3 = R_1 || R_2\$, which is to offset effect by the input bias current. I was trying to derive it by same way in Razavi's textbook but I can’t reach the result of compensating resistor \$R_3=R_1 || R_2\$ (As depicted in below Figure) It would be very appreciated if someone let me understand this. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Not an expert in opamps, but I think R3 has no influence. And this is not an integrator.

Comment: See this thread: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/189949/82111